Workbox is not returning the cached page following a 303 redirect after a POST response
I have this workbox service worker setup:
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/7.1.0/workbox-sw.js');

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    ({ url }) => !url.pathname.includes("."),
    new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate(),
);

self.skipWaiting();

workbox.core.clientsClaim();

and it is working very good!
Now I have a page with a form to add a new todo: /todos/new with a simple <form method="post"> in it.
After the POST request the server returns a redirect 303 - /todods.
In the browser (Chrome) I can clearly see the POST /todos/new request with the redirect response and a new request GET /todos.
The issue is that the GET /todos is not handled by Workbox.
I expect it to serve the cached version of /todos (is already in cache of course).
For example, for the others GET requests (/todos included) I get in the browser console messages from Workbox like this:
workbox Router is responding to: /
workbox Router is responding to: /todos

but for the GET /todos after the POST /todos/new workbox is not stepping in.
Why?
